# merging variable amount of files under matching columns

Tags: vba, file, excel

I have 3 open Excel files which i have opened using this code;

```
Dim myWorkbooks As New Collection

 Sub GetFile()
 Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, i As Long, x As Variant
  fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files    (*.*), *.*", , "Select Files To Be Opened", , True)

 If Not IsArray(fNameAndPath) Then
  If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub Else fNameAndPath = Array   (fNameAndPath)
    End If

 For i = LBound(fNameAndPath) To UBound(fNameAndPath)
Set x = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath(i))
myWorkbooks.Add x
 Next
End Sub
```

i merged all the Sheets i Need in one Workbook. There is a mastersheet called "KomKo" in this Workbook. And i have other Sheets which are "data (2)" , "data (3)" and "data(4)". These Sheets can be more then 4 so i might have Sheets called "data(11) " and so on. I would like to be able to copy Column C of all "data" Sheets and paste it to Column A of "KomKo" Sheet. i should be able to paste These values to the next empty value of that Column A.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

So, after you have corrected your question, this code should do the desired work:

```
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet

Set masterSheet = Sheets("Komko")

'Variable to save the used Range of the master sheet
Dim usedRangeMaster As Integer

Dim ws As Worksheet

'loop through each worksheet in current workbook
For Each ws In Worksheets

    'If sheetname contains "data" (UCase casts the Name to upper case letters)
    If InStr(1, UCase(ws.Name), "DATA", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        'calculate the used range of the master sheet
        usedRangeMaster = masterSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

        'Variable to save the used Range of the sub sheet
        Dim usedRangeSub As Integer

        'calculate the used range of the sub sheet
        usedRangeSub = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

        'copy relevant range from the subsheet
        ws.Range("C1:C" & usedRangeSub).Copy

        'paste the copied range after the used range in column a
        masterSheet.Range("A" & usedRangeMaster).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: But don't forget to add some references if the data sheets are in another workbook(see the other answer)

Comment: this will work for all sheets containing "data" in their name e. g. "123data123", "asdfdatafdsfa", "data1234", "data 4342" and so on. It doesn't matter if "data" is written in small or capital letters

Comment: this pastes the desired Content to row number 9323 although the next empty row was at row number 323. How can i fix this ?

Comment: This is probably because of the way usedRangeMaster is calculated, It holds the last row that has data in it. so you need a different way to calculate this. Maybe a For loop that counts until it finds the first empty cell/row in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a collection containing the relevant workbooks, you can just loop through these and copy the relevant stuff into your main wb.

So define a variable for the master sheet(to be able to refer to it)
And one Variable inside the loop which holds the "subsheet":

```
Dim mastersheet As Workbook

Set mastersheet = ThisWorkbook 'Assuming the code is inside the master sheet

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In myWorkbooks

    'Copy stuff

    'Example to get a value from the "subsheet"
    mastersheet.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = wb.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
Next wb
```

Then inside the loop, copy column c for example and paste it into column a of the master sheet:

```
wb.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C1").EntireColumn.Copy
mastersheet.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: For Each wb In myWorkbooks----> this gives an error as it sais myWorkbooks is empty. how can i fix this ?

Comment: This For Each has to be used after the myWorkbooks.add X, otherwise it is indeed empty

Comment: i have then deleted that but still i get an error by--> wb.Sheets("sheet1").Range("C1").EntireColumn.Copy
mastersheet.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Comment: which error do you get? have you replaced "sheet1" with your actual sheet names?

Comment: actually i think i should edit my question. My current Situation is following. Before your answer i had all the Sheets i Need in one Workbook. There is a mastersheet called "KomKo". And i have other Sheets which are "data (2)" , "data (3)" and "data(4)". These Sheets can be more then 4 so i might have Sheets called "data(11) " etc so ist variable. Now i want to merge These "data" Sheets in to "Komko" and i would like them to match the previous condition, Column C of "data" Sheets must copied and pasted under Column A of "Komko"